# Bulk insert images into SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I want to insert images in this way:

```
DECLARE @lpath varchar(100)
SET @lpath = 'd:\Photo\5604.jpg'

--insert into Photos(id, Photo, Path)
SELECT 
    4144, *, @lpath
FROM 
    OpenRowSet(BULK @lpath, Single_blob) AS i
```

but it's not working

If I execute the code like this:

```
SELECT 
    1, *, @lpath
FROM 
    OpenRowSet(BULK N'd:\Photo\5604.jpg', Single_blob) AS i
```

it works well.

How to execute script like in the first way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use variables in `OpenRowSet`, try to use dynamic SQL like this:

```
DECLARE @lpath NVARCHAR(100) 
SET @lpath = 'd:\Photo\5604.jpg'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql='SELECT 4144, *, ''' + @lpath + '''
          FROM OpenRowSet(BULK ''' + @lpath + ''', Single_blob) AS i'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Tnx.
I solved problem using dSQL but hope that have another way.