# How to insert multiple colum with bulk

Tags: sql, image, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I have a table with four columns.  I want to insert an image in one of the columns. I don't know how to write the query for all this together.

This is a query to insert an image in the database and it is working fine.

```sql
INSERT INTO DatabaseImageTable ([image_name], [image])
SELECT 'SQL Server Image', *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\images\sql-server-image-file.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) image;

CREATE TABLE [country](
    [country_name] [nvarchar](10),
    [country_code ] [int](10),
    [image name] nvarchar(100),
    [image] varbinary(max)
;
```

Comment: If you have two queries and simply want to put them into one file, you can separate the queries with a `GO` statement.
E.g. `CREATE DATABASE...;` GO `INSERT...;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulk insert images into SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377118/bulk-insert-images-into-sql-server-database)

Comment: I think I have not explained well. if you look at my create querry it have four colom. would you please write insert or suggest query for this table?.

Comment: I have not got the answer yet

Comment: I dont know how to right the insert query for this table.